# Using HttpModules to modify the response sent to the client

Tags: asp.net

I have two production websites that have similar content. One of these websites needs to be indexed by search engines and the other shouldn't. Is there a way of adding content to the response given to the client using the HttpModule?

In my case, I need the HttpModule to add  to the response sent to the when the module is active on that particular web.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to handle the `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event of  the application as it is run just before the `IHttpHandler` processes the page itself:

```
public class NoIndexHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
  public void Dispose() { }

  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += AttachNoIndexMeta;
  }

  private void AttachNoIndexMeta(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    if (page != null && page.Header != null)
    {
      page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<meta name=\"robots\" value=\"noindex, follow\" />"));
    }
  }
}
```

The other way of doing it, is to create your own `Stream` implementation and apply it through `Response.Filters`, but that's certainly trickier.